# Showing colum on different table with count sql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
tbl_don
- id_donatur
- id_program
- ...
```

and

```
tbldonasi
- id_donatur
- id_program
- ...
```

I want to show following data from these tables.

```
| id_program | id_donatur |
---------------------------
| 1          | 2          |
| 2          | 3          |
```

where the `id_donatur` column is counted from table 1 and 2

I have run this query

```
select A.id_donatur, A.id_program from tbl_don A UNION all select B.id_donatur, B.id_program from tbldonasi B
```

But I am confused how to completed this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a **group by** clause on the union. Something similar to below:

```sql
select U.id_program, count(U.id_donatur) 
from 
   (select A.id_donatur, A.id_program 
    from tbl_don A 
    UNION all 
    select B.id_donatur, B.id_program 
    from tbldonasi B) AS U 
GROUP BY U.id_program
```